# The top two rows of a table not working in Html while using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a Tic Tac game but there is some problem probably in Javascript file thats why when
any of the boxes of top row are clicked they are not responding ... while the third one does
Please help

```js
var move = 1;
var play = true;

$("#board tr td").click(function() {

  if ($(this).text() == "" && play == true) {
    if ((move % 2) == 1) {
      $(this).append("X");
    } else if ((move % 2) == 0) {
      $(this).append("O");
    }
    move++;
  } else {
    console.log("Enter correct input");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="board">
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Asutosh can u help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always a bit tricky to relay on the `text()` of a cell being `""` because there might be some space left in the markup which can invalidate your condition.

To quickly fix the issue you can add `trim()` to make sure to remove all leading and trailing space in the markup.

I've created a JSFiddle to show the working implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/6wdha0rx/10/

```
var move = 1;
var play = true;

$("#board tr td").click(function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "" && play == true) {
    if ((move % 2) == 1) {
      $(this).append("X");
    } else if ((move % 2) == 0) {
      $(this).append("O");
    }
    move++;
  } else {
    console.log("Enter correct input");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```js
var move = 1;
var play = true;

$("#board tr td").click(function() {

  if ($(this).text() == "" && play == true) {
    if ((move % 2) == 1) {
      $(this).append("X");
    } else if ((move % 2) == 0) {
      $(this).append("O");
    }
    move++;
  } else {
    console.log("Enter correct input");
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="board">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working code for that.

```js
var move = 1;
var play = true;

$("#board tr td").click(function() {

  if (!($(this).text().trim()) && play) {
    if (move % 2) {
      $(this).append("X");
    } else {
      $(this).append("O");
    }
    move++;
  } else {
    console.log("Enter correct input");
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="board">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```